# Why the results are different from using merge(lista+listb)

Tags: python

Here I'm trying to merge this two lists, making one whit all items.

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

def flatten(n):
    s=[]
    for x in n:
        s.append(x)
    return s

print flatten(n)
```

I'm trying to have as a result

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

but I'm getting

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

I dont understand why, I think I'm clearly assigning each value to the list 's' in the for loop.

Comment: fyi, adding lists will combine them. `x = n[0] + n[1]`  will get  `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Answer (score 3):

You're appending to the list. Each sublist is appended to the new list as its own item, exactly the way it was originally. You want to extend the list instead:

```
s.extend(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use extend, instead of append

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

def flatten(n):
    s=[]
    for x in n:
        s.extend(x)
    return s

print flatten(n)
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [list.extend](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), append is appending each sublist not adding just the contents. `x` is each sublist so just appending the sublist is obviously going to give you a list of lists again.

You can also use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to  flatten the  list:

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

print(list(chain.from_iterable(n)))
```

Or use a [list comp](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

print([ele for sub in n for ele in sub])
```

Comment: Ahem! [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Comment: Can also add [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :D

Comment: @BhargavRao, I see you have the gold python badge ;)

Comment: Yep! Got it as a pre-birthday gift :D